# Python string concatenation of multiple strings separated without comma

Tags: python, python-3.x

Though it might seem a very trivial question, I still want to know the principle behind it. When we write multiple strings together without any comma,python concatenates them. I was under the impression that it will throw some error. Below is a sample output:

```
print('hello''world')
# This will output helloworld
```

Even if I write those multiple strings in the python REPL, the output will be the concatenated form of the strings. Can anyone please explain the logic behind this operation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation.

> Multiple adjacent string or bytes literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation.
>   Thus, `"hello" 'world'` is equivalent to `"helloworld"`. This feature can be used to reduce the number of backslashes needed, to split long strings conveniently across long lines, or even to add comments to parts of strings